# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, instruments

I have this message below when the app crashes, I'm still new to coding. How can I use this to find the root cause?

```
An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'MainScene' object (zombie) at address: 0x1f3f5d70.
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's purely symptomatic. You've turned on zombies to detect whether a message is being sent to a dangling pointer. It is. But why the pointer has dangled, and when it started to dangle, is completely unknown; it happened earlier.

Comment: Is there a better way to test?

Comment: The test is over. It succeeded. You're done. - The question is why you released a MainScene object to which you are still maintaining a pointer. That's not easy if you're using ARC; if you're _not_ using ARC it's very easy (you may have said `release` to something you didn't own). You can use Instruments to track the lifetime retains/releases of your MainScene object(s), and you can inspect your code closely, but you haven't given any info so I can't say more.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use this to find the root cause?

Look at the line where the crash occurs. What object are you trying to sending a message to? Where did you get that pointer?

Debugging is detective work, and you're looking at a crime scene. You can look at the evidence -- the spot where the crash happened, the call stack, etc. You can also run tests to check hypotheses: set break points at earlier points in the code to see if the pointer is valid there. Look for the place where the object is deallocated.

Keep at it. Every bug has a cause.